# In 7 card stud with low card(s) wild, is A-2-3-4-5-J-J a five card high straight?

Tags: seven-card-stud, straight

There was a disagreement that the hand was a 5 high straight as the player contended that his NON-wild card straight was valid. It was pointed out to the player that in "Low Card Wild" games an Ace could not be considered low as a five high straight would mean by sequence an Ace would have to be his Low Card. Again, the hand was A-2-3-4-5-J-J. What is the proper read for this hand?

Comment: Yes, that's a wheel (a 5-high straight). It would be defeated by a 6-high straight or better. I cannot speak to your wildcard rules--that's up to the house.

Comment: if low cards are all wild, this is not a wheel but a royal flush.

Answer (score 1):

In low games with the exception of 2-7, a wheel is always the lowest hand, unless you decide something different before the game starts.

> Blockquote Ace could not be considered low as a five high straight would mean by sequence an Ace would have to be his Low Card.

In any game I have dealt (which is many) high hands and low hands can use the same cards. The case of the wheel is the classic example the wheel counts as a five low and five high straight.

And what Lee said, it is up to the house to play the rules they want.

Comment: "In any game I have dealt (which is many) high hands and low hands can use the same cards." The caveat is that an Ace can be a high card **or** a low card, or not both. For instance, J Q K A 2 is not a straight.

Comment: There are three sets of lowball rules in common (?) use: ace-to-five, in which aces are low and straights and flushes don't exist ("California lowball"); deuce-to-seven, in which aces are only high, and straights and flushes are bad ("Kansas City lowball"); and ace-to-six, in which aces are only low and straights and flushes are bad ("London lowball").